# Is there a field in django that will deal with html?

Tags: django, forms, html-parsing

I have a form on my site which a user can use to submit an article, but I've just considered that they may use html to embed a video. I have the body of an article as a TextField, but rather than me parse the html manaually, is there anything that will do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextField that you are using is a good option, do not parse the HTML text, store it raw in the DB, and render it in a template when needed - preview/view published article. You should only provide a mechanism for the user that helps creating formatted articles / embedding files etc. A good option would be  [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), as far as I am concerned there are plugins that enable uploading media.